# Why is my video not playing in my website from the playlist?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load a video playlist in my website and i enabled my JavaScript as per the instructions in Google. This is my code and I don't know where the problem is. When I run the localhost page, the video doesn't load when I click on the link. I can't figure out what the problem is.

I am using Windows 64 bit OS. I was wondering if this is the problem of my JavaScript but I have my JavaScript enabled.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
                    $("#videoarea").attr({
                        "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
                        "poster": "",
                        "autoplay": "autoplay"
                    })
                })
                $("#videoarea").attr({
                    "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
                    "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
                })
            })
        </script>
        <style>
            #playlist {
                display: table;
            }
            #playlist li {
                cursor: pointer;
                padding: 8px;
            }
            #playlist li:hover {
                color: blue;
            }
            #videoarea {
                float: left;
                width: 640px;
                height: 480px;
                margin: 10px;
                border: 1px solid silver;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="" src=""></video>
        <ul id="playlist">
            <li movieurl="Lemonade.mp4">Lemonade</li>
            <li movieurl="mirror.mp4">Sintel</li>
            <li movieurl="http://html5example.net/static/video/html5_Video_VP8.webm">Resident Evil</li>
            <li movieurl="http://www.ioncannon.net/examples/vp8-webm/big_buck_bunny_480p.webm">Big Buck Bunny</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid to run anything with the term 'big buck bunny' at work...

Comment: @EngineerDollery:- Hahaha, i had no problem running it thou!

Answer (score 0):

You have not loaded jQuery in the code you provided, but you are using `$` as if jQuery were loaded.

Adding a link to load it like the following will take you to the next step:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing things working for the fourth link:

http://jsfiddle.net/JasonAller/j0cwqtLj/

The first two links are local, and the third is being blocked by the site hosting it.